# MS CRM Online data abnormalities

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-online

I have a client who migrated to MS CRM Online in April, they've reported a number of cases where their data has updated itself, for example:

- Custom entity data records disappear and the related record entities then show another record value.
- Ownership of accounts/contacts changed. 2500+ accounts changed ownership in a 10 minute window. (Surely this can't be human error). The audit log show one specific user having updated all 2500+ records.

There are no scheduled tasks running other than those configured and managed by Microsoft.

There is only one plugin that automatically creates a SharePoint Doc folder for the activities entity and moves any attachments to the SharePoint Folder.

Any ideas/suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Could be a couple of causes, those that jump to mind; a user manually bulk editing records or [cascading relationship behaviour](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309412.aspx#BKMK_CascadingBehavior),

Comment: I can't say hand on heart they're not tinkering but I don't believe the users have the know how to bulk edit. The Cascading Relationship could be something. Many thanks and I'll make as answered if this turns out to be the case.

Comment: cascading doesn't effect the records that are being altered; there also no system jobs showing any bulk imports.